# onActivityResult no longer being called after onDestroy

Tags: android, onresume, activity-state

onActivityResult is giving me major headaches. My little game has a title / menu screen.  Upon clicking "new game" an Activity is launched which creates a SurfaceView for my game world.

When playing, the player can enter buildings in the game world. Upon entering a building I launch the activity for that particular building from my SurfaveView.  Here is an example:

```
   Intent storeIntent = new Intent(mMinerClass, GeneralStore.class);
   storeIntent.putExtra("player", mPlayer.save());   
    ((Activity) mContext).startActivityForResult(storeIntent, Miner.REQUEST_STORE);
```

mMinerClass is defined in the game Activity onCreate:

```
  mMap .mMinerClass = Miner.this;
```

mMap is the SurfaceView. 
I'm passing a bundle containing the state of the player. In onActivityResult I grab the bundle returned by the store activity and update the player state.

```
 public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
      Bundle player = intent.getExtras();
      mMap.mSavedPlayer = player;
  }
```

mSavedPlayer is later used to set the new player state.

**All the above works generally**

I can enter stores, buy stuff, leave and the player is updated correctly.

**The problem** manifests when I press the Home button (or someyimes back button) and onDestroy gets called. My onDestroy method does nothing besides call super.onDestroy();

After onDestroy() gets called onActivityResult no longer gets called.

So:

1) I play the game, everthing works great.

2) I press home and ondestroy is called

3) relaunch my game via launcher icon

4) Resume game. I can still enter and leave stores but onActivityResult is no longer called.

Here is some logcat output. I'm logging each time I enter a relevant method.

```
  App start.  Resuming a saved game
  07-03 00:33:04.759: ERROR/Miner(4014): -->onCreate
  07-03 00:33:04.819: ERROR/Miner(4014): -->onStart
  07-03 00:33:08.329: ERROR/Miner(4014): -->onResume

  Enter store and buy stuff 2 times.  Everything working great.
  07-03 00:33:30.419: ERROR/Miner(4014): -->onPause
  07-03 00:33:31.279: ERROR/Miner(4014): -->onStop
  07-03 00:33:35.069: ERROR/Miner(4014): -->onActivityResult
  07-03 00:33:35.069: ERROR/Miner(4014): -->onRestart
  07-03 00:33:35.069: ERROR/Miner(4014): -->onStart
  07-03 00:33:36.709: ERROR/Miner(4014): -->onResume
  07-03 00:33:42.129: ERROR/Miner(4014): -->onPause
  07-03 00:33:43.289: ERROR/Miner(4014): -->onStop
  07-03 00:33:55.279: ERROR/Miner(4014): -->onActivityResult
  07-03 00:33:55.279: ERROR/Miner(4014): -->onRestart
  07-03 00:33:55.279: ERROR/Miner(4014): -->onStart
  07-03 00:33:56.879: ERROR/Miner(4014): -->onResume

  Back button pressed bringing me to title screen
  07-03 00:35:26.283: ERROR/Miner(4014): -->onPause
  07-03 00:35:27.153: ERROR/Miner(4014): -->onStop
  07-03 00:35:27.333: ERROR/Miner(4014): -->onDestroy

  Resume Game
  07-03 00:36:12.953: ERROR/Miner(4014): -->onCreate
  07-03 00:36:13.003: ERROR/Miner(4014): -->onStart
  07-03 00:36:14.663: ERROR/Miner(4014): -->onResume

  Enter store and buy stuff twice.  No more onActivityResult

  07-03 00:36:52.063: ERROR/Miner(4014): -->onPause
  07-03 00:36:52.863: ERROR/Miner(4014): -->onStop
  07-03 00:36:59.913: ERROR/Miner(4014): -->onRestart
  07-03 00:36:59.913: ERROR/Miner(4014): -->onStart
  07-03 00:37:01.593: ERROR/Miner(4014): -->onResume
  07-03 00:37:23.353: ERROR/Miner(4014): -->onPause
  07-03 00:37:24.173: ERROR/Miner(4014): -->onStop
  07-03 00:37:29.173: ERROR/Miner(4014): -->onRestart
  07-03 00:37:29.173: ERROR/Miner(4014): -->onStart
  07-03 00:37:30.793: ERROR/Miner(4014): -->onResume
```

I'm posting this from my phone so excuse any dumb typos.

I appreciate any insight y'all can provide regarding this. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry I thought that would be automatic.  I think I awarded it correctly now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should put additional attention to this line:

```
((Activity) mContext).startActivityForResult(storeIntent, Miner.REQUEST_STORE)
```

Are you sure mContext is the correct activity? I suspect it's not the current activity but the reference to another activity instance, the first one that was closed before. Can you use "this" instead of mContext?

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to investigate this, it sounds like it makes sense.  I'm a bit of a java dunce.  Thanks for giving me some direction, the bounty is yours if it works.