# Why is my activity calling onDestroy when I try to call onActivityForResult from adapter?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-adapter, android-lifecycle, startactivityforresult

In the main activity there is a fragment that has **RecyclerView**. When a user clicks an item in the RecyclerView, I am calling `((Activity)v.getContext()).startActivityForResult(intent, Config.REQUEST_ATTENDEES)` from my adapter and I handled this request on my `onActivityResult` method in my main acitivity. And inflate fragment again from `onActivityResult`. My `onActivityResult` get triggered but after get triggered, my main activity calls `onDestroy`. Here below are resources that I looked:

[can we call startActivityForResult from adapter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11882927/can-we-call-startactivityforresult-from-adapter)

[onActivityResult no longer being called after onDestroy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3183068/3918109)

I'm thinking second one can be my problem but I'm not sure because in my adapter, `(Activity)v.getContext()` should be my main activity. Any suggestion would be nice.

Comment: Yeah it may be possible that your context is not reference of current activity. Please check your  **RecyclerView** adapter constructor that you are passing correct context from fragment or not?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:
getActivity().startActivityResult(intent,Configs.REQUEST_ATTENDEES)

Comment: I can't call getActivity() in `viewHolder.getCv().setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) { //I start activity here for result }
        });`